# What does "디엠 씨도 멋쟁이가 되어 보라고 드리는 거예요" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I have a short dialogue like this:

> 와, 스카프네요

> 올가을에 유행한다고 해요. 디엠 씨도 멋쟁이가 되어 보라고 드리는 거예요.

What does "디엠 씨도 멋쟁이가 되어 보라고 드리는 거예요" mean? I can't understand this sentence because it has the phrase "라고 드리는 거예요"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -라고 here still has a sense of quotation, just that the thing being quoted is something that hasn't actually been said. Basically "I'm giving it (the scarf) with the meaning of 'try becoming a cool person'". It is fairly common to use 라고 like this, quoting something that wasn't explicitly said but easily could have been said/conveys the person's intentions.

Answer (score 2):

###### Connective ending “**-라고**” indicates the purpose of the following clause.

“**디엠 씨도 멋쟁이가 되어 봄**” (“—for 디엠 to be a dapper person, too.”) is the reason why “**(제가) (디엠 씨에게) (스카프를) 드리는 거예요.**” (“I give you that—”).

“디엠 씨도 멋쟁이가 되어 보**라고** (제가 디엠 씨에게 스카프를) 드리는 거예요.”

- “I give you that for you to look dapper, too.”
- “I give you that because I want you to look dapper, too.”

---

Comment: Thanks, but I thought 라고 is used for indirect quotations  (=라고 하다), so why "connective ending “-라고” denotes the purpose of the following clause."?

Comment: @ThaiTrinh I asked NIKL about that, and yes, it is “[-라고⁵](https://stdict.korean.go.kr/search/searchView.do?word_no=100651&searchKeywordTo=3),” that is used for indirect quotation. I got confused as well: it was not “_taken_” from somewhere else; how come it is “_quotation_?” Other unofficial Korean dictionaries (that are not the canonical one, “표준 국어 대사전.”) clearly differentiate such a sense from the quotational sense of the word…. Anyways, you can just think it as having another sense other than quotation.